# Time optimization of parallel long-running tasks

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

### Intro

I am working with a complex external library, where I am attempting to execute it's functionality on a large list of items. The library does not expose a good async interface, so I'm stuck with some quite old-fashioned code.

My aim is to optimize the time it takes to complete a batch of processing, and to demonstrate the problem without having to include the actual 3rd party library I have created an approximation of the problem below

### Problem

Given a non-async action, where you can know the "size" (ie, complexity) of the action in advance:

```
public interface IAction
{
    int Size { get; }
    void Execute();
}
```

And given there are 3 variants of this action:

```
public class LongAction : IAction
{
    public int Size => 10000;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}

public class MediumAction : IAction
{

    public int Size => 1000;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

public class ShortAction : IAction
{
    public int Size => 100;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

How could you optimize a long list of these actions, so that when run in some sort of parallel fashion, the entire batch completes as fast as possible?

Naively, you could just throw the entire lot at a `Parallel.ForEach`, with a reasonably high Parallelism and that certainly works - but there must be a way to optimally schedule them so some of the biggest are started first.

To further illustrate the problem, if we take a super-simplified example

- 1 task of size 10
- 5 tasks of size 2
- 10 tasks of size 1

And 2 available threads. I could come up with 2 (of many) ways to schedule these tasks (The black bar being dead time - nothing to schedule):

[image]

Clearly the first one completes earlier than the second.

### Minimal Complete & Verifiable Code

Entire test code if anyone fancies a bash (try to make it faster than my naive implementation below):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MainAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        var list = new List<IAction>();
        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) list.Add(new LongAction());
        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) list.Add(new MediumAction());
        for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) list.Add(new ShortAction());


        var swSync = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Parallel.ForEach(list, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 20 }, action =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Starting action {action.GetType().Name} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            action.Execute();
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Finished action {action.GetType().Name} in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        });
        swSync.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Done in {swSync.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
    }
}


public interface IAction
{
    int Size { get; }
    void Execute();
}

public class LongAction : IAction
{
    public int Size => 10000;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
    }
}

public class MediumAction : IAction
{

    public int Size => 1000;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}

public class ShortAction : IAction
{
    public int Size => 100;
    public void Execute()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
}
```

Comment: These type problems are called "Packing Problems" where you attempt to minimize the  time or number of resources needed to solve a problem.  There is no algorithm to solve issue without trying every possibility,  but there a lots of white papers written with algorithm to achieve good solutions.

Comment: Thanks @jdweng I'll look into that. I hadn't associated this problem with the packing problem but I guess you're right.

Comment: Looking into the extra info (which I think you've added since I started my answer), I guess provided you know how many threads there are available, you could pre-allocate tasks based on size somehow

Comment: @Jamiec `Parallel.ForEach` is meant for data parallelism, not asynchronous execution. It's tottaly *un*suitable in your case. It works by partitioning into roughly as many partitions as there are cores and uses one task per partition to process its data without synchronization penalties. It even uses the *current* thread for processing which is why it appears to block.

Comment: @Jamiec a far better option would be an ActionBlock from the TPL Dataflow library, with a specific DoP. An action block is roughly speaking a worker that reads data from its input queue and processes it. By default DOP is 1, as dataflow blocks are meant to be used in a pipeline with each block running on its own task.

Comment: @jamiec simply ordering the actions by descending size would allow any worker implementation to keep itself busy. Do you expect unexpected large jobs to arrive while processing? You could use separate processing blocks for this case

Comment: @jamiec check [Custom Partitioners for PLINQ and TPL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl?view=netframework-4.7.2). The scenario you describe is similar to chunk partitioning and load balancing. Load balancing over ordered arrays and lists [is already available](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_Partitioner_Create__1___0___System_Boolean_). I've forgotten that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A relatively quick and dirty solution is to use [a load-balancing partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/custom-partitioners-for-plinq-and-tpl?view=netframework-4.7.2#configuring-load-balancing-partitioners-for-plinq) on top of an action list sorted by decreasing size

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(a => a.Size).ToArray();
var partitioner=Partitioner.Create(sorted, loadBalance:true);

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, options, action =>...);
```

Using just these two lines performans improves by about ~30%, just like the other answers.

PLINQ partitions data and uses a separate tasks to process an entire partition at a time. When the input size is known, as is the case with IList-derived arrays and lists, the input is partitioned into equally sized chunks and fed to each worker task.

When the size isn't known, as is the case with iterator methods, LINQ queries etc, PLINQ uses chunk partitioning. A chunk of data is retrieved at a time and fed to the worker tasks.

Another option, which I'd forgotten, is *load balancing* on top chunck partitioning. This applies chunk partitioning using small chunks to arrays and IList-derived input. The load-balancing [Partitioner.Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.partitioner.create?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Concurrent_Partitioner_Create__1___0___System_Boolean_) overloads return OrderablePartitioner instances, so the order of the IAction items is preserved

The same can be achieved with an `IEnumerable<T>` source by specifying the `EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering` option :

```
var sorted = list.OrderByDescending(a => a.Size);
var partitioner=Partitioner.Create(sorted,EnumerablePartitionerOptions.NoBuffering);
```

This will create an OrderablePartitioner that uses chunk encoding

Comment: This was definitely the winner. With my test on an unordered list, time was around 14s. using a partitioner with `loadBalance:true` reduces that to 9s. Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the bat I'd say that the problem is as follows.

You have a list of integers and a limited number of summers.
You want an algorithm that sums the integers into the summers so that the maximum value of summers is the minimum possible.

E.g.:

```
list = 1, 4, 10, 2, 3, 4
summers = 3

summer(1): 10
summer(2): 4 + 4
summer(3): 3 + 2 + 1
```

As you can see the bounding factor is the longest running task. The shorter ones are easily served in parallel or in less time. It's similar to Knapsack, but in the end boils down to a very simple "longest first" ordering of the tasks.

The pseudo code (with my *invented* classes) would be:

```
while (taskManager.HasTasks())
{
    task = taskManager.GetLongestTask();
    thread = threadManager.GetFreeThread(); // blocks if no thread available
    thread.Run(task);
}
```

This is just pseudo code, not parallel/async and blocks. I hope you can derive from it something useful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends.  On my hardware your contrived example (modified so the sleeps are 1000,100 and 10ms as I don't have all day) is ~30% faster (~15s vs ~22s) if I simply change the loop to run all the long tasks first:

```
Parallel.ForEach(list.OrderByDescending(l=>l.Size), action => ...
```

But of course this depends *entirely* on what the loads are of these tasks.  If two different tasks utilise the same resource heavily (e.g. a shared database) then there may be very limited gains from running those two tasks in parallel as they'll just end up locking each other for periods at some level.

I would suggest you need a more in-depth analysis and then to somehow group the tasks based on how 'parallel-able' they are based on what they actually do, and try to ensure you run as many parallel threads as possible with as many 'compatible' tasks as possible...  And of course if one particular task seems to always take as long as all the others put together, ensure that one is started first....

Very hard to give better advice with the details given here.

Comment: There is no database or other such shared resource (except CPU of course), all tasks are completely independent

Comment: Notice that Parallel.ForEach does not preserve the order within the input list - the sort by the task size will not hold.

Comment: @YoniV that's not necessarily true, one can specify a custom partitioner that will also take care of ordering, or even implement a packing algorithm.

Comment: @YoniV - I wasn't sure whether it would, but the change I outlined above definitely made a difference.  could of course have been luck, but I did 3 runs before which were all around 22s, then 3 runs after which were around 15s.  I accept this behaviour may change with compiler versions etc. but I don't really see why Parallel wouldn't simply pull items off the list in whatever order they come and allocate threads to them, and if you've passed it what I assume is probably an `IOrderedEnumerable<>` or similar I don't see why it wouldn't get tasks in that order until all threads were allocated...

Answer (score 1):

Sorting by task size in descending order and then using TaskFactory for executing each in a different task shaved off significant running time. The parallelism level remained 20.
The results were: 114,676ms vs 193,713ms in your original sample. (~40% improvement)

EDIT: In your specific example the list is sorted from the get-go anyway, but Parallel.ForEach does not preserve the input order.

```
static async Task MainAsync()
{
    var list = new List<IAction>();
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) list.Add(new LongAction());
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) list.Add(new MediumAction());
    for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++) list.Add(new ShortAction());

    Console.WriteLine("Sorting...");
    list.Sort((x, y) => y.Size.CompareTo(x.Size));
    int totalTasks = 0;

    int degreeOfParallelism = 20;
    var swSync = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    using (SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(degreeOfParallelism))
    {
        foreach (IAction action in list)
        {
            semaphore.Wait();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Starting action {action.GetType().Name} on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                    action.Execute();
                    sw.Stop();
                    Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss}: Finished action {action.GetType().Name} in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms on thread {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
                }
                finally
                {
                    totalTasks++;
                    semaphore.Release();
                }
            });
        }

        // Wait for remaining tasks....
        while (semaphore.CurrentCount < 20)
        { }

        swSync.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Done in {swSync.ElapsedMilliseconds}ms");
        Console.WriteLine("Performed total tasks: " + totalTasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason to use raw tasks and semaphores to specify a DOP. Higher-level classes in the TPL (PLINQ, Dataflow, Parallel) work using tasks, not threads.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you elaborate - `Parallel.ForEach` doesnt seem to honour the order.

Comment: @Jamiec as I said, Parallel is inappropriate in the first place. This isn't a data parallelism problem. `Parallel` will partition the data before processing which means expensive actions may end up in the same partition.

Comment: @Jamiec You can avoid that by [specifying your own partitioner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Parallel_ForEach__2_System_Collections_Concurrent_Partitioner___0__System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelOptions_System_Func___1__System_Func___0_System_Threading_Tasks_ParallelLoopState___1___1__System_Action___1__) but I'd use an ActionBlock with a large DOP first to keep things simple - N workers pulling from the same input queue, and feed the most expensive actions first